# Can't remove line breaks in php shell_exec() returnvalue

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec, line-breaks

I am trying to grab some data from ifconfig but I only get the frist line stored in my variable.

I run

```
//First off, find out whether we're using eth or wlan
$wlanTest = shell_exec('/sbin/ifconfig wlan|egrep -o "wlan|inet addr:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|RUNNING"');
$log = "| contents of wlan test: " . $wlanTest;
echo $log;
myLog($log);
```

I only get the first line of the answer back. The full answer is:

```
eth
inet addr:192.168.99.193
RUNNING
```

But all I get in my variable is

```
eth
```

I have tried with php implode() and str_replace() to remove \n characters from $wlanTest but no luck.

Comment: Did you try replacing / with //?

Comment: No, is that a special line break character in linux cmd prompt? I only knew of \n for linux linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that shell_exec() return you all data you need with `var_dump` because i see you command

`egrep -o "wlan|inet addr:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|RUNNING"`

select rows with wlan not eth, and then try to use this for replacement of line breaks `$ethTest = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'',$ethTest)`